# Checking numbers are balanced (within 1 of each other) (PHP)

Tags: php, math, numbers

I know there must be 100 ways to do this - but can someone recommend the 'best/most simple' method to check if three integer variables are within one point of each other.

```
$a = 1; $b = 2; $c = 1;
```

As each var is within 1 point of each other the formula required should return TRUE;

Can anyone suggest the best functions/method to do this. Thanks in advance

Comment: max($a,$b,$c) and min($a,$b,$c) will give the range, which should be $max-$min<=1; assuming no negatives etc..

Comment: aha - using max/min looks like a good method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thought i'd go the extra mile here

```
function scope_check()
{
    // usage: bool scope_check(mixed $range, mixed $val1 [, mixed $val2 [,mixed $...]])
    $array=func_get_args();
    if(sizeof($array)<=1) return false;
    $range=array_shift($array);

    $max=max($array);
    $min=min($array);

    if($max-$min<=$range) return true;
    return false;
}

$valid=scope_check(1, -10, -11, -12, 4, 5 ,7);
if($valid) echo 'valid'; else echo 'not valid';
```

Comment: wow - only just saw this on the page refresh, nice one dude :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function scope_check()
{
    $array=func_get_args();
    $max=max($array);
    $min=min($array);

    if($max-$min<=1) return true;
    return false;
}

$valid=scope_check($a, $b, $c);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the [`abs()`](http://php.net/abs) function:

```
abs($a-$b) <= 1 && abs($a-$c) <= 1 && abs($b-$c) <= 1
```